# How to resolve a LuaLaTeX font error regarding missing or bad metric data?

Tags: luatex

I always get the following error when I want to compile my tex file with lualatex:

```
Font \TU/lmr/m/n/10.95=[lmroman10-regular]:+tlig; at 10.95pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad. \normalsize
```

I have no clue what I changed or let's say, I replaced overpic with tikz, got another error, changed it back and now I have this error.

log file after minimal example:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.07.0 (MiKTeX 2.9.6630 64-bit)  (format=lualatex 2018.8.14)  14 AUG 2018 17:34
 restricted system commands enabled.
**document.tex
(./document.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Lua module: luaotfload-main 2017/01/29 2.80001 OpenType layout system.
Lua module: lualibs 2017-02-01 2.5 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2017-02-01 2.5 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended co
llection.(using cache: C:/Users/gerd_/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/luatex-cache/gene
ric)
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is C:/Users/gerd_/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/
2.9/luatex-cache/generic/names.
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader “fontloader-2017-02-11.lua” from kpse
-resolved path “C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-2
017-02-11.lua”.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@state = 1
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 2
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@syllabe = 3
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version “3.027”
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' at position 1 in `define_font'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 4
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is C:/Users/gerd_/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/
2.9/luatex-cache/generic/names.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_
font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' at position 2 in `luaotfload.patch
_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' at position 3 in `luaotfload.patch_font
'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' at position 4 in `luaotfload.patch_font'
.
luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.422 seconds
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 1 language(s) loaded.
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/koma-script/scrreprt.cls"
Document Class: scrreprt 2018/03/30 v3.25 KOMA-Script document class (report)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty"
Package: scrkbase 2018/03/30 v3.25 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent ba
sics and keyval usage)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty"
Package: scrbase 2018/03/30 v3.25 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent b
asics and keyval usage)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty"
Package: scrlfile 2018/03/30 v3.25 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
)))
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty"
Package: tocbasic 2018/03/30 v3.25 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
\scr@dte@tocline@numberwidth=\skip41
\scr@dte@tocline@numbox=\box26
)
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `toc'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `toc' on input line 136.
Package tocbasic Info: defining new hook before heading of `' on input line 1667
.
Package scrreprt Info: You've used standard option `11pt'.
(scrreprt)             This is correct!
(scrreprt)             Internally I'm using `fontsize=11pt'.
(scrreprt)             If you'd like to set the option with \KOMAoptions,
(scrreprt)             you'd have to use `fontsize=11pt' there
(scrreprt)             instead of `11pt', too.
Class scrreprt Info: File `scrsize11pt.clo' used to setup font sizes on input li
ne 2328.

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize11pt.clo"
File: scrsize11pt.clo 2018/03/30 v3.25 KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt)

luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from C:/Users/gerd_/AppData/Local/M
iKTeX/2.9/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc
! Font \TU/lmr/m/n/10.95=[lmroman10-regular]:+tlig; at 10.95pt not loadable: met
ric data not found or bad.
<to be read again> 
relax 
l.112 \normalsize

I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.

) ("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty"
Package: typearea 2018/03/30 v3.25 KOMA-Script package (type area)
\ta@bcor=\skip42
\ta@div=\count79
Package typearea Info: You've used standard option `a4paper'.
(typearea)             This is correct!
(typearea)             Internally I'm using `paper=a4'.
(typearea)             If you'd like to set the option with \KOMAoptions,
(typearea)             you'd have to use `paper=a4' there
(typearea)             instead of `a4paper', too.
\ta@hblk=\skip43
\ta@vblk=\skip44
\ta@temp=\skip45
\footheight=\skip46

! Arithmetic overflow.
\\typearea ...by100 \divide \ta@temp by\@tempdima 
                                                  \@tempcnta =\ta@temp \ifnu...
l.1706 \typearea[current]{current}

I can't carry out that multiplication or division,
since the result is out of range.


Package typearea Warning: Bad type area settings!
(typearea)                The detected line width is about 27410792%
(typearea)                larger than the heuristically detected line width.
(typearea)                You should e.g. decrease DIV, increase fontsize
(typearea)                or change papersize.

Package typearea Info: These are the values describing the layout:
(typearea)             DIV  = 10
(typearea)             BCOR = 0.0pt
(typearea)             \paperwidth      = 597.50793pt
(typearea)              \textwidth      = 418.25555pt
(typearea)              DIV departure   = -27410792%
(typearea)              \evensidemargin = 47.2316pt
(typearea)              \oddsidemargin  = -12.5192pt
(typearea)             \paperheight     = 845.04694pt
(typearea)              \textheight     = 595.80026pt
(typearea)              \topmargin      = -25.16531pt
(typearea)              \headheight     = 17.0pt
(typearea)              \headsep        = 20.40001pt
(typearea)              \topskip        = 11.0pt
(typearea)              \footskip       = 47.6pt
(typearea)              \baselineskip   = 13.6pt
(typearea)              on input line 1706.
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@chapter=\count81
\c@section=\count82
\c@subsection=\count83
\c@subsubsection=\count84
\c@paragraph=\count85
\c@subparagraph=\count86
\scr@dte@part@maxnumwidth=\skip47
\scr@dte@chapter@maxnumwidth=\skip48
\scr@dte@section@maxnumwidth=\skip49
\scr@dte@subsection@maxnumwidth=\skip50
\scr@dte@subsubsection@maxnumwidth=\skip51
\scr@dte@paragraph@maxnumwidth=\skip52
\scr@dte@subparagraph@maxnumwidth=\skip53
\abovecaptionskip=\skip54
\belowcaptionskip=\skip55
\c@pti@nb@sid@b@x=\box27
\scr@dte@figure@maxnumwidth=\skip56
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `lof'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `lof' on input line 6247.
\c@figure=\count87
\scr@dte@table@maxnumwidth=\skip57
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `lot'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `lot' on input line 6264.
\c@table=\count88
Class scrreprt Info: Redefining `\numberline' on input line 6433.
\bibindent=\dimen102
)

LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [ngerman].

(./document.aux)
\openout1 = document.aux

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
 [1

Missing character: There is no H (U+0048) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no e (U+0065) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no l (U+006C) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no l (U+006C) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no o (U+006F) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no W (U+0057) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no o (U+006F) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no r (U+0072) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no l (U+006C) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no d (U+0064) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ! (U+0021) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 1 (U+0031) in font nullfont!
] (./document.aux))

Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 2397 strings out of 494447
 100000,221844 words of node,token memory allocated
 375 words of node memory still in use:
   2 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 attribute, 49 glue_spec, 3 attribute_list
, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:21,3:2,4:1,5:24,6:1,7:24,8:1,9:9
 6582 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+200000
 14 fonts using 591871 bytes
 42i,6n,66p,9102b,150s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
Output written on document.pdf (1 page, 837 bytes).

PDF statistics: 6 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 100000000)
```

Comment: Please post a minimal compilable code example (MWE) reproducing this error.

Comment: @TeXnician I would but it is not compileable and I can't post my few 100 lines file here cause like I said, I have no clue what is wrong. I tried to use \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  and \usepackage[EU2]{fonttenc}, non works

Comment: Try to break it down to what is necessary that the error still appears and then post it here. That way you will help us help you.

Comment: Try if a minimal example loading only the class article, no packages and containing only "hello world"  breaks. If yes quite the compilation by hitting "x" and enter on your keyboard and then show the log-file.

Comment: Even following doesn't work: 
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside,ngerman]{scrreprt} % [11pt, parskip]{scrartcl} % scrartcl %
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}



\begin{document}
xxx
\end{document}

Comment: Then please post the log file of that run.

Comment: log file added.

Comment: @vogs so that should be your MWE, and you could add that, and the log it produces, to your question, but basically you have not got the latin modern fonts installed, so you have a broken tex installation, or perhaps just a broken luaotfload cache

Comment: check in the miktex console if you have the `lm` package installed.

Comment: Was on vacation, couldn't try anything. It works now fine at my desktop PC but not on my laptop. @DavidCarlisle how can I fix the luaotfloat cache? yes, lm package is installed

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it has been solved by a reinstallation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was really a broken MikTex installation. Wasn't able to update or even uninstall MikTex. I did the brute force method with deleting everything MikTex related (in the programs and user folder on my windows laptop) and ran a registry cleaner (CCleaner). Then I installed MikTex again and et voila, it works.